# What is the meaning of 一点で?

Tags: words, meaning

I saw [一点]{いってん}で used a handful of times in examples like [一点]{いってん}で[撃ち抜く]{うちぬく} or [一点]{いってん}で[討つ]{うつ} and while I know what the word itself means, I don't understand how it's being used with these verbs.

Could anyone explain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO it's mostly used in anime and it not a common usage. It serves to exaggerate (similar to "super ultra..." etc.) the fact that the action is a very focused, single action.

More common usage in everyday speech is e.g. `一点で支える`

Comment: If it would imply a focused action, wouldn't it rather be 一点に? Like in shooting **at** one single point.

Comment: @DavidJablonski: that won't be grammatical, unless it's `弾を一点に撃つ`. The original sentence is def. unusual to begin with (e.g. I'm not sure what `一点で討つ` is supposed to *really* mean, it's like saying `Beat the opponent on a single point` / if you are `撃ち抜く`ing, it's logical that it's done on a single point so `一点で` sounds redundant). But while it sounds unusual, で does sound grammatical.